# How can I call mixed mode C# dll from Delphi using BTMemoryModule?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dll, unmanaged

I have a DLL written in C# that uses Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports library and exports functions with `[DllExport]`.

I can load it fine with `LoadLibrary`, and call its exported functions. When I tried to load it into memory using `BTMemoryModule`, the call of entry point  (DllMain - DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) `TDllEntryProc` (in function `BTMemoryLoadLibary`) returns false. How can I load such a DLL using `BTMemoryModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading DLLs from memory is not unsupported. Any code that does this is using unsupported hacks to do so. The system provides `LoadLibrary`, `LoadLibraryEx` etc. to perform this task, and they require the DLL to be present on disk.

Your DLL is a mixed mode .net assembly, and it requires special treatment by the loader. The system loader, as invoked by calls to `LoadLibrary`, `LoadLibraryEx` etc. knows how to perform the actions needed to load a mixed mode .net assembly. The BTMemoryModule code does not perform these special actions.

If you are going to be able to load such a module from memory, you will need to either find a library that supports such modules, or write your own loader code. Frankly, I doubt that such a library exists. More realistically you should load the DLL from disk.

Comment: It' would be interesting to know what these special actions are ... or maybe where to find out what it should be.

Comment: They aren't documented. You can simply load the DLL from disk, the only supported way to load modules.